# Difference between "Tired of Waiting" and "Tired from Waiting"

Tags: difference, usage

I noticed that both "Tired of Waiting" and "Tired from Waiting" are in use, and valid. But what differences do they have, or are they identical? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

"Tired of waiting" means that you have waited for so long that you are emotionally tired and do not want to wait anymore.

"Tired from waiting" means that you have waited for so long that you are physically tired.

Comment: I would add that "tired of waiting" is used 99% of the time.