# "tired from work" or "tired of work"

Tags: word-choice

"My body is tired from work" sounds a bit wrong to me, but I am not sure. Google gives both  variants in big numbers, but Google doesn't guarantee that all the results are correct in terms of English grammar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "Tired of Waiting" and "Tired from Waiting"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/difference-between-tired-of-waiting-and-tired-from-waiting)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - No. Because the noun there is "waiting", not "work", and there is no   statement declaring that the same principle works for other nouns.

Comment: It does work for other nouns!

Comment: @KateBunting - It's good to know that, but that page doesn't say that.

Comment: _Tired from doing something_ = physically tired. _Tired of doing something_ = bored by too much of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different meanings.

"tired from work" means that work has made it tired.

"tired of work" is an idiom that means it doesn't want any more work.

So, if your work is heavy manual labour (but you enjoy your job), you might say "I'm tired from work".  If your job is boring data entry you might say "I'm tired of work - I want a holiday".

As "tired of work" is an emotion, it would be strange to say "my body is tired of work" (your body doesn't have feelings).  But it would be fine to say "My body is tired from work."

Comment: Note you can say "I'm tired of chicken" to mean "I've eaten a lot of chicken recently, and I want something different".  It doesn't mean that you are exhausted.